# Ошибка ValueError: unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 8 при использовании переменной в регулярном выражении

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти в тексте некоторый текст, который находится между двумя символами (например "@")

```
templateTest = 'ddddffs@rusjjd@sdsvvv@xcvdfb @'
simvol = '@'

def findReplasement(sourse, start, end):
    regular = re.compile('%a(.*?)%b' %(start,end), re.IGNORECASE)
    result = regular.findall(sourse)
    return result

x = findReplasement(templateTest, simvol,simvol)
print(x)
```

Но в этом случае выдаётся ошибка:

> ValueError: unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 8

При этом, если не использовать переменные, то всё работает:

```
regular = re.compile('@(.*?)@', re.IGNORECASE)
```

> ['rusjjd', 'xcvdfb ']

В чём ошибка?

Comment: а тупо `start + '(.*?)' + end` ?

Comment: очень странно, но это была первая версия и при задании аргументов функции "start" распознавал как сумму __add__ и выдавал ошибку. а сейчас заработало, спасибо!

Comment: нету у оператора `%` типа преобразования `b`

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что во выражении

```
'%a(.*?)%b' %(start,end)
```

`%b` значит *конверсию выражения типа **integer*** (до двоичной системы), и вы во вызове функции

```
findReplasement(templateTest, simvol,simvol)
```

используете параметр `simvol` типа **string**.

Нужно применить (дважды - тоже для `%a`) описатель формата `%s` для типа **string** - то значит, вместо

```
regular = re.compile('%a(.*?)%b' %(start,end), re.IGNORECASE)
```

используйте

```
regular = re.compile('%s(.*?)%s' %(start,end), re.IGNORECASE)
```

и вывод из вашей программы будет

> `['rusjjd', 'xcvdfb ']`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [88]: pat = re.compile(r'{}(.*?){}'.format(simvol,simvol), flags=re.I)

In [89]: re.findall(pat, templateTest)
Out[89]: ['rusjjd', 'xcvdfb ']
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы найти все фрагменты текста между указанными границами start, end с помощью вашего регулярного выражения:

```
import re

def findall_inbetween(text, start, end):
    return re.findall('(?i)' + '(.*?)'.join(map(re.escape, [start, end])), text)
```

[`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) используется чтобы заэкранировать символы, которые являются специальными в регулярных выражениях. К примеру, `.` (точка) заменяется на `\.` (чтобы буквально точку найти, а не произвольный символ).

Пример:

```
>>> findall_inbetween('a@b@c@d@', *'@'*2)
['b', 'd']
```